# A Question about the Kurtosis

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Problem:
Show that if a binomial distribution with $n = 100$ is symmetric, its
coefficient of kurtosis is 2.9.
Answer:
First, I am interpreting the term symmetric to mean that
$p = q = \frac{1}{2}$. The general formula for $\alpha_4$ (kurtois) is:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha_4 &=& 3 + \frac{1 - 6pq}{npq} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
So, I just subsitute in the values.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha_4 &=&
    3 + \frac{1 - 6(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})}{100(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})} \\
\alpha_4 &=& 3 + \frac{1 - \frac{6}{4}}{100(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})}
    = 3 + \frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{100(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})} \\
\alpha_4 &=& 3 + \frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{25} \\
\alpha_4 &=& 2.98 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
This is not the value I seek. So, instead of using the book's short cut
formula, I am going to use the definition of krtosis.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha_4 &=& \frac{E( (x - u)^4 )}{{\sigma}^4} \\
\text{with }u &=& E(x) = np = 100(\frac{1}{2}) \\
u &=& 50 \\
E( (x - u)^4 ) &=&
    \sum_{i=0}^{100} { (i-50)^4 {{100}\choose{i}}(\frac{1}{2})^{100} } \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha_4 &=& \frac{E( (x - u)^4 )}{{\sigma}^4} \\
\text{with }u &=& E(x) = np = 100(\frac{1}{2}) \\
u &=& 50 \\
E( (x - u)^4 ) &=&
    \sum_{i=0}^{100} { (i-50)^4 {{100}\choose{i}}(\frac{1}{2})^{100} } \\
\end{eqnarray*}
To evaluate the above expression, I used the following R script:

```
sum = 0
for( i in 0:100 ) sum = sum + ((i-50)^4) * choose(100,i) * (.5^100)
```

After running the script, I find
\begin{eqnarray*}
E( (x - u)^4 ) &=& 1862.5 = \frac{3725}{2} \\
{{\sigma}^2} &=& npq = 100(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2}) = 25 \\
{{\sigma}^4} &=& (25)^2 = 625 \\
\alpha_4 &=& \frac{ \frac{3725}{2} }{625} = \frac{3725}{2(625)}\\
\alpha_4 &=& \frac{745}{2(125)} = \frac{149}{2(25)} = \frac{149}{50} \\
\alpha_4 &=& 2.98 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Do you think the book is wrong?

Bob

Comment: It looks like the answer in the book is wrong. 2.98 is the correct result